# Unable to access HttpServletRequest inside a custom MessageBodyWriter

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am trying to get an instance of the HttpServletRequest inside my custom MessageBodyWriter. I am currently using a member variable annotated with @Context. However, when a request first uses the writer - Jersey throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.". As far as I can tell, Jersey was still trying to instantiate the writer.

Actually, I have commented out every use of the request variable - I am just declaring it.

I'm trying to achieve something similar to [this](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/wink/trunk/wink-server/src/main/java/org/apache/wink/server/internal/providers/entity/html/HtmlProvider.java).

I'm using Jersey 2 on GAE sdk - It seems to be a bug, does anybody have any workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Please update the question with the sourcecode to provide more information.

Comment: @unwichtich, I have switched to Resteasy, so I don't have the exact code anymore. However, I have provided a link to a java file which is almost exactly the same. In fact, my code was much simpler because I ultimately commented out every usage of the request and response variables (was just declaring them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Googlers, it's possible this was related to this Jersey bug, which has been marked resolved:

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2355

I had this issue and, having found first this question and then that bug, updating my Jersey version fixed it.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: I've done some Googling but that link seems to have fallen off the edge of the Internet into the Oracle user experience.